# Cam I make Identity part of the container when creating MVC controllers?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, identity

When my controller uses an object which taked identity as input, I could of course do this:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public MyController()
    {
        _repository = new MyRepository(HttpContext.User.Identity);
    }
}
```

However manual construction of the repository (or any other object which needs identity) is not very elegant. A better way would be to use the IOC-container for injecting identity

Is there a way to add identity to the IOC-container, so I could just do this:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public MyController(MyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Identity is of course useful in all kinds of objects. It can be used in a DB-repository to add metadata like updating user. Or it can be used by an object accessing another service for impersonation

Comment: You can have IIdentityProvider interface as a dependency to the repository. It should have method or property to return identity. And the implementing class should access the identity from the HttpContext and return in the implementing property or method.

Comment: But then would the IdentityProvider constructor need to have the HttpContext as parameter in the constructor ? Then I would need to have HttpContext registered in the container. Isn't that the same problem ?

Comment: That's not needed... Your class should directly access `HttpContext.User.Identity`. the class will be just a wrapper around `HttpContext.User.Identity` and not dependent on HttpContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @Chetan's suggestion, but a little different, this worked for me. I added these registrations in my Startup:

```
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<IIdentityProvider, IdentityProvider>();
```

The first line will make the IHttpContextAccessor avaialable for injection. I can then build my IdentityProvider like this:

```
internal class IdentityProvider : IIdentityProvider
{
    public IdentityProvider(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        Identity = contextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity;
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; }
}
```

IIdentityProvider is then available for MyRepository and other objects where it is needed

```
public class MyRepository
{
    private readonly IIdentity _identity;

    public MyRepository(IIdentityProvider identityProvider)
    {
        _identity = identityProvider.Identity;
    }
}
```